# Figures and Captions

Tags: floats, captions

In Overleaf:  after I inserted a figure into my latex document, I also inserted a caption, but the caption doesn't show on the PDF version.  Here's the code I entered; am I missing something to prevent the caption from showing?

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
Zippia: The Career Expert
\includegraphics{Mathematica. HW 1.jpg}
\caption{Computer Programmers in the United States}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TSE. Please post a [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/134805), instead of a code snippet.

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to see the preamble?

Comment: What happens if you use `\captionof{figure}{Computer Programmes in the United States}` ? That option is made available by the `caption` package in the preamble.

Comment: I mean a full document that can be compiled.

Comment: Alchemist:  \captionof ?

Comment: Partial Solution:  I entered a width of .75 after \includegraphics.  However, now the figure is too small, and the figure title appears at the bottom of the page after the page number.

Comment: Probably the problem because of the space in image file name, better to remove the space in file naming of the image, then try, e.g., `Mathematica. HW 1.jpg` to `Mathematica.HW1.jpg`

Answer (score 1):

This is the simplest way in which what you want to do works:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
Zippia: The Career Expert
\includegraphics{example-image-a}
\caption{Computer Programmers in the United States}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

The outcome is below.

If your caption is not showing, it is probably because you are using another package that has some conflict with the rest of the code or because inadvertently you changed a setup for the caption. Try to reproduce the code fragment above with your figure.

[image]